# How to mock multiple objects which will return non-null values

Tags: java, mocking, easymock

I need help in creating mocking two objects simultaneously.
If I set the return value of first mock obj i.e. mockClassA to `null`, it is working fine. I'm using annotations `@Mock`, `@TestSubject` of EasyMock. And if I don't set the first mock expectation's return as `null`, I'm seeing the following error.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: last method called on mock is not a void method`

Here is the code, I'm trying:

```
    EasyMock.expect(mockClassA.getValfromDB()).andReturn(ValA);
    EasyMock.replay();
EasyMock.expect(mockoClassB.makeRestCall(EasyMock.anyString())).times(2).andReturn(httpResponse);
    EasyMock.replay();
```

If EasyMock doesn't support mocking multiple objects in a single method, I'm allowed to use Mockito, PowerMockito, EasyMockSupport. Please feel free to suggest me something from those libraries too.

P.S: I already tried using `replayall()` from EasyMockSupport. But it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could able to debug my code and found that I'm giving the no of times in wrong way.

Changing the line

```
EasyMock.expect(mockClassB.makeRestCall(EasyMock.anyString())).times(2).andReturn(httpResponse);
EasyMock.replay();
```

to

```
EasyMock.expect(mockClassB.makeRestCall(EasyMock.anyString())).andReturn(httpResponse);
EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(2);
EasyMock.replay();
```

has resolved my issue (Observe `expectLastCall.times(2)`).

[Ref: TutorialsPoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/easymock/easymock_times_min_max.htm)

Answer (score 0):

A mock must be passed to the `replay()` method. So your original code nor the answer are working. However, it is true that the `times()` must be after the `andReturn()`.

So a correct code would be

```
expect(mockClassA.getValfromDB()).andReturn(ValA);
expect(mockClassB.makeRestCall(anyString())).andReturn(httpResponse).times(2);
replay(mockClassA, mockClassB);
```

or this with `EasyMockSupport`:

```
expect(mockClassA.getValfromDB()).andReturn(ValA);
expect(mockClassB.makeRestCall(anyString())).andReturn(httpResponse).times(2);
replayAll();
```

Note that I'm using static imports. It makes the code much more agreeable to the eyes.

Comment: I tried `.times(2)` after `andReturn()` as well. But it didn't work for me. But `.expectLastCall().times(2)` worked for me. Although both look similar, I'm not sure what is the exact difference. I would greatly appreciate if someone can explain it here.

Comment: `expectLastCall` should only be used with void methods. And it is actually optional. It actually exists to do special things like `expectLastCall().andThrow()`. I guarantee that what I wrote works. If it doesn't in your case, then there's something you are not telling us and you should provide a complete example.